# Routing multiple style of pages along with multiple views in Angular 1

Tags: angularjs, routes, ngroute

I have this code from a tutorial that routes to all the pages related to the main type of document in the application:

```
angular.module('loc8rApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);

  function config ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/home/home.view.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: '/common/views/genericText.view.html',
        controller: 'aboutCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      })
      .when('/location/:locationid', {
        templateUrl: '/locationDetail/locationDetail.view.html',
        controller: 'locationDetailCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      })
      .when('/register', {
        templateUrl: '/auth/register/register.view.html',
        controller: 'registerCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      })
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: '/auth/login/login.view.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      })
      .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }

  angular
    .module('loc8rApp')
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', config]);
```

I would like to expand the routing to cover a different type of document.  For example, appointments.  So a list of appointments along with a details page for the appointments.  Would I put all these new style of routes within this `$routeProvider.when` sequence?  Or maybe a new file or new function to handle this routing of a completely new type of content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment about a "new type of document" and new "type of content" throws me off here. You are still just routing to an HTML document/content. It may be a different section of your site, which is what I think you meant by those statements.

With that said how you setup your routing is up to you but there is no reason you can't add the routes to your appointment pages in the same "when" collection. I like all my routes in the same place for maintenance and visibility. But, depending on the size of your app that can make your route file hard to deal with. So it is a little personal preference and conditionally driven.

Also just as an FYI. I would look at using [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) instead of the default Angular router. It has more power, but that is just food for thought for you.